# Proper way to make numpy array of ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy

the following code achieves what I want to accomplish, but uses python lists and is probably very inefficient. Please let me know if there is a way to do the following purely with Numpy:

```
def makeImageArray(count):
    l = []
    for i in range (count):
        l.append(image)
    res = np.array(l)
    return res
```

Where image is a numpy array of shape (1200,1200,3).

Thank you so much!

Comment: Look into [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) or [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

Comment: You are doing the right thing - start with a list of images you want to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using `numpy.stack()` ([reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html))

If you have multiple images you want to add to the new array you can use this

```
import numpy as np

image_0 = np.random.rand(1200,1200,3)
image_1 = np.random.rand(1200,1200,3)

stack = np.stack((image_0, image_1))
stack.shape

>>> (2, 1200, 1200, 3)
```

If you just want to stack one array multiple times

## Edit

If you want to stack the same image:

```
image = np.random.rand(1200,1200,3)
count = 10
stack = np.stack([image for _ in range(count)])
stack.shape
>>> (10, 1200, 1200, 3)
```

Comment: For this stack and array are the same.

Comment: You are correct, but I think using stack makes the code more clear.

Comment: stack provides a different error/warning if the arrays don't match in size.

Comment: Thats true, however it is deprecated/not good to append/store ndarrays with different shapes or lengths in an ndarray. And here it was onbly asked for images of the same size.